# How to use Bouncy Castle for encrypting J2ME apps with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, encryption, java-me, bouncycastle

I imported bouncy castle jar file into `javabuildpath`.

While running my application i got the following error:  `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/crypto/engines/AESLightEngine`

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

What is `javabuildpath`??

Open up the file `.classpath` and see if your bouncycastle.jar is there. 
Most likely it is not.

Comment: I mean in project properties ->Java Build Path->Libraries i added bouncycastle.jar file. I checked .classpath file, bouncycastle.jar file path is available in that still i getting the error:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/crypto/engines/AESLightEngine

 - java.lang.Class.invoke_verify(), bci=0

 - java.lang.Class.initialize(), bci=117

 - java.lang.Class.forName(), bci=0
 - com.sun.midp.main.CldcMIDletLoader.newInstance(), bci=1

Comment: Have you checked if the `AESLightEngine` class is in the bouncycastle.jar? Maybe its in a different library

Comment: I download `bcprov-jdk16-145.jar` and it's inside there. Is this the file that is added in `.classpath`? And what kind of application are you running? A Main class?

Comment: bcprov-jdk16-145.jar is added in .classpath, no error in compile time.  But still getting error while running the midlet 

*** Error ***
A problem occured during deploying application from http://127.0.0.1:1411/MP3Player.jad
Reason:
Corrupt JAR, error while reading: test/MIDPTest.class